# Unable to ping between ESXi host and Netapp storage on the same switch

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi, storage, netapp

I am unable to ping between ESXi host and Netapp controller that are both connected on the same switch and configured for private IP addresses. Yet I CAN ping between 2 Esxi hosts and between 2 controllers on the same switch using the same IP addresses. The switches are configured to uplink to a Juniper core. Not sure why I am unable to have connectivity between the two.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, what's the actual problem you're having?  The only thing pings reliably measure is the ability to send or receive pings.

Comment: In addition, you haven't given us much detail to work with. `My car won't start even though the gas tank is full and the battery is charged`.

Comment: I am configuring the Esxi host to use NFS via private IP address on the storage controller. I am unable to assign the storage because the host does not have any connectivity to the storage controller VIF which is configured to use the private IP. The ESXi host reports that it "cannot connect to NFS server".

Comment: I am configuring the Esxi host to use NFS via private IP address subnet on the storage controller. I am unable to assign the storage because the host does not have any connectivity to the storage controller VIF which is configured to use the private IP. The ESXi host reports that it "cannot connect to NFS server". Maybe a better way to put this is that does the ESXi host need to be able to ping the storage controller and vice versa for the storage to be added onto the ESXi host? In my lab environment using vm instance of the controller I am able to do so and I can setup the NFS storage fine.

Comment: Ping can tell you if the two hosts have connectivity between them, but only if you know that each host should respond. ICMP is often disabled/blocked and can be a bit of a Red Herring in the sense that you spend too much time trying to figure out why ping doesn't work instead of troubleshooting the real issue. That being said, I would find it hard to believe that the connection is dependent upon ICMP in any way, so in answer to the question `does the ESXi host need to be able to ping the storage controller and vice versa for the storage to be added onto the ESXi host?` I'd tend to answer no.

Comment: It's a iSCSI storage ? If so, please validate your switch config, as it can be two port in two separate VLAN, thus the two appliance would never see each other

Comment: @yagmoth555 - Good point. If VLAN's are in use have you confirmed connections to the correct switch ports, @Altria92?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you can ping the ESX server from the Netapp, you should be able to configure NFS. I'd start by validating that the network is correctly configured on the Netapp. What does an `ifconfig -a` show you? What about `rdfile /etc/rc`?

Your IP address on the NAS can be bound to a physical interface or an interface group with the [ifconfig](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1196979/html/man1/na_ifconfig.1.html) command. The [ifgrp create](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1196979/html/man1/na_ifgrp.1.html) command lets you create interface groups.